# Problem importing a Dump on MariaDB (Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS)

Tags: ubuntu, mariadb, dump

I am writing this post because I cannot import a dump on MariaDB (Version 15.1) using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. I did this dump a few weeks ago and now trying to import it using the command

```
mysql -u root -p database < dumpfile.sql
```

gives me the following error:

> Error at line 46: ASCII ' 0' appeared in the statement but this is not
> allowed unless option --binary-mode is enabled and mysql is run in
> non-interactive mode.

[image: Error 1]

So, I tried with the following command:

```
mysql -u root -p --binary-mode = 1 database < dumpfile.sql
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
Error at line 47: Unknown command '\▒'.
```

[image: Error 2]

I tried to open the database using Notepad ++ and going to line 47 I noticed that it has strange characters:

[image: Error 3]

I don't understand if it's a problem with the dump getting corrupted on export. I want to clarify that some parts are clearly visible, while others are seen with strange characters as in the figure.

I have tried various programs to check the integrity of the database (without success), I have tried to change the encoding of Notepad ++ to UTF-8 but nothing has changed.

I also tried to put `--default-character-set=utf8` in the command to import the database but it always gives me the above error.

I specify that the `.gz` file appears to be corrupt (I cannot open it) and I do not have the possibility to do the dump again as I have the database only in `.sql` format.

**EDIT:**

I tried with the command:

```
mysql --default-character-set=ucs2 -u root -p database < dumpfile.sql
```

But the result is: "Variable 'character_set_client' can't be set to the value of 'ucs2'".

As for the HEX, some points are legible, while others are "00 00 00 [...]".

[image: HEX00]

**EDIT 2.0:**

In my database I find references to "GIT" and code in C #.

1.
[image: git_ref]

2.
[image: c#_ref]

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form and your attempts to resolve the problem. Also, how is this related to programming?

Comment: @NicoHaase I modified the post by inserting the requested data.

Comment: Show us lines 45-47 of the source file.  And show it in hex.  If those lines don't show the "INSERT" command (or whatever), then show us the line with that.  _Probably_ the dump needed to be taken with a different set of parameters.

Comment: @Rick James Here are the required screens:
-Hex: https://ibb.co/hZzvWb2
-Lines of Notepad++: https://ibb.co/Sy2tp9z

Thanks :)

Comment: How was the dump taken?  Perhaps something changed the encoding before the attempt to 'load'?

Comment: In my database I find references to "GIT" and code in C #, do you know why? Thank you :) @Rick James I added some screens to my post.

Comment: Did the data flow through Notepad++?  It may be using ucs2.

Comment: @Rick James As you have seen in my screens, some parts are visible on Notepad ++, others not, as if they had a specific language.
I can't set UCS2 to Notepad ++ because I only see UTF8 and UTF16, how do I do?

Comment: What command performed the export?

Comment: @Rick James i used "mysqldump" command. Thanks.

Comment: @TurboProgram - Was there a parameter to mysqldump specifying default charset?

Comment: @TurboProgram - And...  In the masked out `CREATE TABLE`, are there any columns with charset or collation specifications?  (The could be overriding the tables 'default' of "utf8".)

Comment: @RickJames if I remember correctly I have not entered any parameters in the mysqldump.
And... in the masked out "CREATE TABLE" is only specified the tinyint/int/varchar, the primary key, the unique key and the various keys.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

That is probably `CHARACTER SET ucs2`.

```
mysql --default-character-set=ucs2 -u root -p database < dumpfile.sql
```

That does not impact what charset is used in the tables, only for reading the file.

**History**

MySQL 5.0.67 (Aug, 2008): "ucs2 does not work as a client character set, but attempts to use it as such were not rejected. Now character_set_client cannot be set to ucs2. This also affects statements such as SET NAMES and SET CHARACTER SET. (Bug #31615)".

MySQL 8.0.28 (Jan, 2022): ucs2, macroman, macce, dec, hp8 and "their collations in SQL statements or elsewhere in the MySQL server now produces a deprecation warning."  (That is, they are still supported, but not for very long.)

Conclusion:  It may not be possible to import that data.

Comment: Hi @Rick James, thanks for replying. I tried the command you told me and the result is: "Variable 'character_set_client' can't be set to the value of 'ucs2'". Going deeper into the database in HEX, I noticed that in some places the code is "00 00 00 [...]".Could you tell me what this is due to? Thanks :)

Comment: @TurboProgram - Hmmm...  I added to my Answer.

Comment: In my database I find references to "GIT" and code in C #, do you know why? Thank you :) @Rick James
I added some screens to my post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this commend line

```
mysql -u root -p -h localhost -D database --binary-mode -o < dumpfile.sql
```

**Note**: make sure your sql file is not zipped.

Reffernce  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38383975/mysql-error-ascii-0-while-importing-sql-file-on-linux-server